# syntax error unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR

Tags: php, syntax-error, logical-operators

I'm pretty sure its probably ( or ) that is causing it maybe one too many of them.

```
$filechk1 = "/temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$filechk2 = "/temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc";
$dirchk1 = "/temp/files/" . $batchid . "/" .$data[0] . ".doc";
$dirchk2 = "/temp/files/" . $batchid . "/" . $data[1] . ".doc";

if(is_file($filechk1) && (is_file($filechk2))) || (is_file($dirchk1) && (is_file($dirchk2))){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incorrectly placed parentheses.  Needs to be this.

```
if ((is_file($filechk1) && is_file($filechk2)) || (is_file($dirchk1) && is_file($dirchk2)))
```